# Explaining the resolution rule.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, proof-theory

It is nice to have inference rules explained informally. For example, the rule of Disjunctive Syllogism $((x \lor y) \land \neg y)\rightarrow x$ can be explained as follows: since $x \lor y$ is true, so either $x$ or $y$ is true. But $y$ is false and so $x$ must be true.

I was trying to give a similar informal explanation of why the resolution rule is true but I could not come up with one:
$$((x \lor y) \land (\neg x \lor z))\rightarrow (y \lor z)$$
Is there any such convincing argument?

Comment: [Resolution rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#Resolution_rule) is simply a "generalization" of [modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) : "from $p \to q$ and $p$, derive $q$". In classical logic, you can rewrite $p \to q$ as $\lnot p \lor q$.

Comment: **Hint**: Also, $((x\lor y)\land \neg x) \to y$ from the disjunctive syllogism.

Answer (score 3):

This is vacuously true a lot, which is sort of unsatisfying. The contrapositive is tidier:

By contraposition, if both y and z are false, and since one of x, $\lnot$x is false, then the whole left hand side is false.

Answer (score 2):

One possible explanation:

Since $\neg x\vee z$ is true, so either $\neg x$ or $z$ is true.

If $z$ is true, then $y\vee z$ is true and we are done.

If not, then $\neg x$ must be true i.e., $x$ is false. But $x\vee y$ is also true and therefore it must be that $y$ is true hence again giving the truthness of $y\vee z$.

Answer (score 2):

In classical logic, either $x$ is true or $x$ is false (*tertium non datur*).

In the first case, $\lnot x$ is false and hence from the hypothesis $\lnot x \lor z$ it follows that $z$ is true.

In the second case, $x$ is false and hence from the hypothesis $x \lor y$ it follows that $y$ is true.

Summing up, since one of the two cases ($x$ is true or $x$ is false) holds, then either $z$ is true or $y$ is true, i.e. $y \lor z$ is true.